# Can I connect eight LED strip lights to the same power source?

Tags: led

I want to run led strip lights around my son's bedroom. I have narrowed my choice down to 3528 rgb and 3528 white. I will need a bout 4 strips in each color. My question is can I run these from the same power source?  My idea is .... if it's possible .... to get a splitter with 2 connectors and run the rgb one way and white the other and have them run side by side.

If this is possible what size power source do you recommend and are there  any other items I need to purchase?

Comment: Why not just buy a package containing a power-supply and strip that's long enough?  And if you have RGB why do you need white? (RGB together make white)?

Comment: There is also RGBW, which has alternating RGB and W lights, and 4 channels to control them.   You can buy combo RGBW strips, or you can use RGBW controllers and amplifiers to drive separate RGB and W strips.

Comment: The question lacks critical detail. Strip length and LED count matter, as does the particular power supply. The answer can only be "yes, if...", or "no, but...".

Comment: I think you're looking at one particular product, and assuming all LED strips in existence are similar enough to that one product for differences not to matter... That is incorrect.

Comment: Actually I’d go the even newer rgb+cct which adds a 5th LED to allow white color balancing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on the product have or want to use.
Most good LED RGB-W systems are low votage and subject to specific wiring codes.( Check those of your state and local codes.

5Amps per channel is typical and may require more sophisticated wiring techniques.

Additionally, W in RGB-W is not gerenally bright enough for proper illumination. I assume you have determined this given your product descriptions.
You may find that the wiring is best concealed in a cove.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this since LED lights don't use that much power

Comment: This really doesn't contain much information that's helpful to the OP. Please take our tour to see how better to contribute here.

Comment: It actually may also be bad information if for example voltage drop prevents LEDS near the end to drop out.  There is exact science to calculate this but it can’t be done with the information as currently presented.